# JAXB unmarshalling with enum data without annotation

Tags: java, xml, enums, jaxb

I am new to jaxb. I am trying to marshal/unmarshal some data. Before unmarshalling, I am planing to perform some validations where the xsd contains some enumeration constraints for some fields like this:

```
<xs:element name="beStatus">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="1" />
            <xs:enumeration value="A" />
            <xs:enumeration value="D" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

when i try to validate the xml using this scheme it works perfectly fine. But when I try to unmarshal the same i couldn't get the values for these variables having enum constraints in the class object.
and one more thing the class is not mine so I couldn't use any annotations on it. 
thanks in advance...

Comment: I got the issue but that makes the prblem more complicated. the variables in the class were of char type. I try to use xmlAdapter for character to String. when I use package level annotaion the entire string variables in the class are changed. and also I need to avail this constraint for only to some of my fields(around 50-60 :P). please help...thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried package Level annotation and works fine... thanks to me.... :P